# how do you write some text on a plot using the plot() function

Tags: r

I have a plot and I'd like to write some text on the plot is this possible?

how can I write: "this is my text on the plot"  somewhere on the actual plot?

```
frame1<-data.frame(x = rnorm(4), y=rnorm(4))
plot(frame1$x,frame1$y,main="plot 1")
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use text():

```
frame1<-data.frame(x = rnorm(4), y=rnorm(4))
plot(frame1$x,frame1$y,main="plot 1")
text(x = 1, y= 0.5, labels ="this is my text on the plot")
```

x, y : is the position in your graph.

For more info, see the [text()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) vignette: